# Setting Loop with start and end date

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp

Thats a code a friend of mine helped me with in order to get files from diferent measurement systems, timestamps and layout into on .csv file.
You enter the timeperiod or like in the case below 1 day and the code looks for this timestamps in different files and folders, adjusts timestamps (different Timezone etc.) and puts everything into one .csv file easy to plot. Now I need to rewrite that stuff for different layouts. I managed to get everything working but now I don't want to enter every single day manually into the code :-( , cause I'd need to enter it 3 times in a row --> in order to get the day for one day into one file, `dateFrom` and `dateTo` needs to be the same and in the `writecsv...`section you'd have to enter the date again.

here's the code:

```
from importer import cloudIndices, weatherall, writecsv,averagesolar
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

dateFrom = datetime.strptime("2010-06-21", '%Y-%m-%d')
dateTo = datetime.strptime("2010-06-21", '%Y-%m-%d')
....
code 
code
....
writecsv.writefile("data_20100621", header, ciData)
```

what can I change here so that I get an automatic loop for all data between e.g 2010-06-21 to 2011-06-21

p.s. if i'd entered `2010-06-21`in `dataFrom`and `2011-06-21` in `dateTo` i'd get a huge cvs. file with all the data in it ..... I thought that would be a great idea but it's not really good for plotting so I enden up manually entering day after day which isn't bad if you do it on a regular basis for 2 or 3 days but now a dates showed up and I need to rund the code over it :-(

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should be using [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) and [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), here is an example of how:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

# advance 5 days at a time
delta = timedelta(days=5)

start = datetime(year=1970, month=1, day=1)
end = datetime(year=1970, month=2, day=13)

print("Starting from: %s" % str(start))
while start < end:
    print("advanced to: %s" % str(start))
    start += delta
print("Finished at: %s" % str(start))
```

This little snippet creates a start and end time and a delta to advance using the tools python provides. You can modify it to fit your needs or apply it in your logic.

Comment: thank you that looks great, and what needs to go to the `writecsv` so thatthe data created gets that date automatically?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `writecsv`, but I'm guessing you want to generate file per day, which means putting your whole code inside a loop like I suggested.